# Cloud Run hosted on Firebase Hosting under subdomain not working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, firebase-hosting

I have a Cloud Run service called play which works fine.

I am now trying to host it behind Firebase Hosting, I tried using the Integration UI which is under preview but it fails and just said that is not possible to use it.

So, I am now trying with a `firebase.json` as showed below.

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "play.carimbo.cloud/**",
        "run": {
          "serviceId": "play",
          "region": "us-central1",
          "pinTag": true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I deploy it using a GitHub Action

```
- name: Setup Firebase Hosting
  uses: firebaseextended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
  with:
    channelID: live
    repoToken: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    firebaseServiceAccount: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS }}
    projectId: ${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}
    expires: 30d
```

As you can see below, the deploy works, but when I access https://play.carimbo.cloud I get an 404 from Firebase.

Which steps do I need to do to host it behind Firebase?

[image]